# How to rotate a camera around a mesh

Tags: qt, rotation, qml, mesh, qt3d

Using Qt/QML/C++, I'm trying to build a very basic 3D scene to rotate the camera around a mesh object.

main.cpp

```
#include <Qt3DQuickExtras/qt3dquickwindow.h>
#include <Qt3DQuick/QQmlAspectEngine>

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QtQml>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    Qt3DExtras::Quick::Qt3DQuickWindow view;

    // Expose the window as a context property so we can set the aspect ratio
    view.engine()->qmlEngine()->rootContext()->setContextProperty("_window", &view);
    view.setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
    view.setWidth(800);
    view.setHeight(600);
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```qml
import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.0
import Qt3D.Input 2.0
import Qt3D.Extras 2.0

Entity {
    id: sceneRoot

    Camera {
        id: camera
        projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
        fieldOfView: 25
        aspectRatio: _window.width / _window.height
        nearPlane : 0.1
        farPlane : 1000.0
        position: Qt.vector3d( 0, 0.0, 20.0 )
        upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
        viewCenter: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 )
    }

    OrbitCameraController {
        camera: camera
    }

    components: [
        RenderSettings {
            activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer {
                clearColor: Qt.rgba(0, 0.5, 1, 1)
                camera: camera
            }
        },
        InputSettings { }
    ]

    PhongMaterial {
        id: carMaterial
    }

    Mesh {
        id: carMesh
        source: "resources/aventador.obj"
    }

    Entity {
        id: carEntity
        components: [ carMesh, carMaterial ]
    }
}
```

How do I get the camera to rotate around the mesh object?

Answer (score 2):

The OrbitCameraController allows to move the camera along an orbital path. To make it rotate around the mesh, you could set the viewCenter of the camera to the position of the mesh (translation of the transform of the entity containing the mesh) and use your keyboard/mouse to rotate it around.

So add:

```
Transform{
        id: carTransform
        translation: Qt.vector3d(5.0, 5.0, 5.0) //random values, choose your own
}
```

and add the transform to the components of the entity.
Change the viewCenter of the camera to

```
viewCenter: carTransform.translation
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use a mouse or keyboard to do this.

When you use [OrbitCameraController](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-extras-orbitcameracontroller.html) or [FirstPersonCameraController](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt3d-extras-firstpersoncameracontroller.html) you can't have our control.

I use this [code](https://github.com/parisa-hr/SOrbitCameraController) instead of OrbitCameraController.

```js
Entity{

    id: root
    property Camera camera;
    property real dt: 0.001
    property real linearSpeed: 1
    property real lookSpeed: 500
    property real zoomLimit: 0.16
    
    MouseDevice {
        id: mouseDevice
        sensitivity: 0.001 // Make it more smooth
    }
    
    MouseHandler {
        id: mh
        readonly property vector3d upVect: Qt.vector3d(0, 1, 0)
        property point lastPos;
        property real pan;
        property real tilt;
        sourceDevice: mouseDevice
    
        onPanChanged: root.camera.panAboutViewCenter(pan, upVect);
        onTiltChanged: root.camera.tiltAboutViewCenter(tilt);
    
        onPressed: {
            lastPos = Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y);
        }
        onPositionChanged: {
            // You can change the button as you like for rotation or translation
            if (mouse.buttons === 1){ // Left button for rotation
                pan = -(mouse.x - lastPos.x) * dt * lookSpeed;
                tilt = (mouse.y - lastPos.y) * dt * lookSpeed;
            } else if (mouse.buttons === 2) { // Right button for translate
                var rx = -(mouse.x - lastPos.x) * dt * linearSpeed;
                var ry = (mouse.y - lastPos.y) * dt * linearSpeed;
                camera.translate(Qt.vector3d(rx, ry, 0))
            } else if (mouse.buttons === 3) { // Left & Right button for zoom
                ry = (mouse.y - lastPos.y) * dt * linearSpeed
                zoom(ry)
            }
    
            lastPos = Qt.point(mouse.x, mouse.y)
        }
        onWheel: {
            zoom(wheel.angleDelta.y * dt * linearSpeed)
        }
    
        function zoom(ry) {
            if (ry > 0 && zoomDistance(camera.position, camera.viewCenter) < zoomLimit) {
                return
            }
    
            camera.translate(Qt.vector3d(0, 0, ry), Camera.DontTranslateViewCenter)
        }
    
        function zoomDistance(posFirst, posSecond) {
            return posSecond.minus(posFirst).length()
        }
    }
}
```

Create a new QML class and call it for example `SOrbitCameraController` or anything you want, then use it instead of `OrbitCameraController` and take camera to this class.

Answer (score 0):

I found that all I needed to do was to set the up Vector to zero, I am writing with pyqt so mine looked like this:

```
camera.setUpVector(QVector3D(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

The reason being that after this I was able to lock the right-mouse button controls and rotate around the mesh with the left-mouse button controls.

Answer (score 0):

I found this useful information:

```
Q_INVOKABLE void tiltAboutViewCenter(float angle);

Q_INVOKABLE void panAboutViewCenter(float angle);

Q_INVOKABLE void panAboutViewCenter(float angle, const QVector3D &axis);

Q_INVOKABLE void rollAboutViewCenter(float angle);
```

This is what you want.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).