# Find centroid of imported mesh in QML application

Tags: c++, qt, 3d, qml

In my QML application I'm displaying a custom mesh which is generated from medical images. Now I want the camera to rotate around the center of this meshes.

According to the [answers in this question this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45369210/qt3d-rotate-camera-around-mesh) I have to set the `viewCenter` of the camera to the translation of the mesh. However, the meshes I have are already translated (the centroid is not at [0, 0, 0]) as they are in the coordinate system of a CT/MR scanner.

How can I get the centroid of an imported mesh in order to set the viewCenter accordingly?

In my QML file I have:

```
import Qt3D.Core 2.0
import Qt3D.Render 2.0
import Qt3D.Input 2.0
import Qt3D.Extras 2.0
import QtQuick 2.0 as QQ2

Entity {
    id: sceneRoot

    Camera {
        id: camera
        projectionType: CameraLens.PerspectiveProjection
        fieldOfView: 45
        nearPlane : 0.1
        farPlane : 1000.0
        position: Qt.vector3d(0, 0, 20)
        upVector: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 )
        viewCenter: Qt.vector3d( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 ) // here I should set the viewcenter to the centroid of "organModel"
    }

    OrbitCameraController  { camera: camera }

    components: [
        RenderSettings {
            activeFrameGraph: ForwardRenderer {
                camera: camera
                clearColor: "transparent"
            }
        },
        InputSettings { }
    ]

    PhongMaterial {
        id: material
        ambient: "darkRed"
    }

    Mesh {
        id: organModel
        source: "qrc:/organModel.obj"
    }

    Transform {
        id: transformLiver
    }

    Entity {
        id: torusEntity
        components: [ liver, material, transformLiver ]
    }

}
```